# i'm not able to connect new version of vscode and new version of mysql

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-code

my vscode version is 1.35.1 and newer version of mysql and i'm not able to connect the vscode and mysql, by sitting for 3-4 hrs yet not able to solve the problem,while i'm installing the application of vscode in mysql some popup like 1.2.8 failing the requirements.

i tried extension in vscode of mysql, filling all requirments as host='localhost', username = 'root', password='.......' and i got error as ""Connection error! ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client""

can any one know how to connect both, or provide some article about this trouble or video link

Comment: ... and the "newer version of MySQL" is ? ...   my guess is that the client is attempting to use old school password, but the user in mysql server is defined to use a different authentication protocol. i.e. I would check the contents of `mysql.user` table, and verify the `plugin` column contains `mysql_native_password`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE   I see 29 posts related to this error message, did you find nothing suggested in any of those posts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create or alter a user to change its authentication type to standard. [image: Authentication Type Standard]